# Import of images is stuck at "In progress" since 3 days

Tags: image-upload

I uploaded 3000 images 3 days ago but image processing is still in progress. Can someone give me a fix or tell me why is it so slow?

Comment: Try to upload minimum of records, like 500

Comment: @Aditya are you using magento default import or magmi ?